# Как выбрать изображение при нажатии на него?

Tags: python, tkinter, pil

Здравствуйте! Есть такой код:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

c = Canvas(width=500,height=300,bg="white",cursor="pencil")

pilImage = Image.open("notaall.png")
DO = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pilImage)

c.create_image(100,150,image = DO)
c.create_image(100,200,image = DO)
c.create_image(100,250,image = DO)
c.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Как кликнув на изображение выделить его и например удалить? Удалить нужно только одну из 3 нот

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Рабочий код с пояснениями:

```
...

# Чтобы все работало правильно, нужно добавить отдельный тег для всех изображений (пусть будет 'image')

c.create_image(100, 150, image = DO, tags='image')
c.create_image(100, 200, image = DO, tags='image')
c.create_image(100, 250, image = DO, tags='image')

c.pack()

# Добавляем реакцию на клик мышью на канве

selected = None

def canvas_on_click(event):
    global selected
    # Находим все объекты на canvas в данной точке
    overlap_items = c.find_overlapping(event.x, event.y, event.x, event.y)

    # Оставляем только объекты с тегом image (мы же не хотим, чтобы можно было выделить рамку выделения?)
    overlap_items = tuple(_id for _id in overlap_items if 'image' in c.gettags(_id))

    if overlap_items:
        # Объектов в точке может быть несколько, берем первый попавшийся
        item = overlap_items[0]
        selected = item
        bbox = c.bbox(item)  # получаем ограничивающий прямоугольник объекта (bounding box)
        c.delete('selection')  # Удаляем старую рамку выделения (все объекты с тегом "selection")
        c.create_rectangle(*bbox, outline='red', width=2, tags='selection')  # Добавляем рамку выделения
    else:
        # Клик мимо объектов
        selected = None  # Ничего не выделено
        c.delete('selection')  # Удаляем рамку выделения

c.bind('<1>', canvas_on_click)

# Удаление выделенного элемента нажатием на кнопку

def remove_selected():
    # Если что-то выделено - удаляем
    if selected is not None:
        c.delete(selected)  # Удаляем выделенный объект (по его id)
        c.delete('selection')  # Удаляем рамку выделения (по тегу)

b = Button(root, text='Remove', command=remove_selected)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Но есть один вопрос. Можете прокомментировать(более подробно) эту строку кода:overlap_items = tuple(_id for _id in overlap_items if 'image' in c.itemcget(_id, 'tags'))@insolor

Comment: @Raccoon, буквально, создать `tuple` состоящее из `_id` из набора `overlap_items`, для которых выполняется условие `'image' in c.itemcget(_id, 'tags')` (т.е. в набор тегов объекта с данным `id` входит тег `'image'`).

Comment: Честно спасибо Вам огромное. Много неизвестного в Вашем коде,буду учить и подтягивать уровень.@insolor

Comment: @Raccoon [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

```
c.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: event.widget.delete('all'))
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но оно удаляет все. Мне нужно только то на что я кликну. Можете подсказать как это сделать?@Sergey Gornostaev